# Create storyboards that use XIB files

Tags: ios, list, storyboard, xib

I'm creating an app which includes a lot of re-usable views.
For this to work I created my main storyboard, and then the xib files for the re-usable views.

I then figured out a way to 'extract' the view from the xib file (drag the view out of the controller) which gave me the ability to freely resize the view in the xib file.

The outcome was that I had a bunch of custom sized views (xib's) and my main storyboard which would dynamically build lists from the xib files to use as sub views on it's main view.

Everything works perfectly in the simulator, but my question is, is it 'legal' to do it this way. Or would apple reject the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ok to do so,Infact you can created custom sized views in storyboard itself but they will be embedded in viewcontroller anyway

Make the size to freeform in the attribute inspector of viewcontroller and you can have the customised sized view in viewcontroller itself

[image]